# jQuery .html() doesn't set value of text area

Tags: jquery, textarea

```
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#test').click(function(){
            videofix();
        });
    }
    function videofix(){
        $('#article').text($('#article').val().replace(/\[video\](http:\/\/(www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+))\[\/video]/g,'[video=youtube;$3]$1[/video]'));
    }
            </script>
    <textarea id="article" name="article"></textarea><br>
    <input type="button" id="test" value="test">
```

Basically my problem is, the videofix function when called, while working it does not replace the text of the textarea. I've actually copied my code out of this to jsfiddle and tried it there and it worked. So I'm not sure what the hell is going on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For setting a value to textarea you should use `val()` method instead of `html()`;

```
$("#article").val("something");
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked strange that the jsfiddle copy worked though and the actual one didn't.

Answer (score 2):

The only textarea I see in your code has `id="article"`.  And you never set it's value using `.html()` as far as I can see.

Anyway, if .html() doesn't work, maybe try this instead:

```
$("#article").empty().append(data);
```